# How to read multiple input in looping

Tags: c, loops

```
printf("number to input: \n");
scanf("%d",&y);

for(x=0;x<y;x++){
    scanf("%d",&num);
}

printf("Numbers entered: %d \n",num);
```

let assume that we entered value 4 .
*scanf* will looping 4 times and entered a single value 1,2,3,4 for each loop

The final output should display `1 2 3 4`

any ideas?

Comment: you need to declare an array - otherwise how can you store multiple values in order to print them..

Comment: @amdixon Linked list is an alternative way, but it is too complex for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an array to store the values.
You will have to allocate dinamically because the number of data varies and it can be determined by user input before reading the data.

Here is a sampie implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int x,y=-1;
    int *num;
    printf("number to input: \n");
    scanf("%d",&y);
    if(y<0)return 1;
    num = malloc(sizeof(int)*y);
    if(num==NULL)return 1;

    for(x=0;x<y;x++){
        scanf("%d",&num[x]);
    }

    printf("Numbers entered: ");
    for(x=0;x<y;x++){
        printf("%d ",num[x]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what does free(num) at the end do?

Comment: It will release the buffer allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: Computers are good at counting; humans are not.  There are ways to avoid the need for the user to say how many entries will be made, such as provide a big array (4096 entries, perhaps), or reallocate when more space is needed.  The code should be checking the return value from `scanf()` anyway.